# Accessible Nested Tabs Angular

Tags: angular

The below example section demonstrates a tabs widget that implements the tabs design pattern. In this example, a new panel is displayed only after the user activates a tab with either Space, Enter, or a mouse click. Typically, manual activation of tabs is only necessary when panels cannot be displayed instantly, i.e., not all the panel content is present in the DOM

Tabs are a set of layered sections of content, known as tab panels, that display one panel of content at a time. Each tab panel has an associated tab element, that when activated, displays the panel. The list of tab elements is arranged along one edge of the currently displayed panel, most commonly the top edge.

Terms used to describe this design pattern include:

Tabs or Tabbed Interface
A set of tab elements and their associated tab panels.
Tab List
A set of tab elements contained in a tablist element.
tab
An element in the tab list that serves as a label for one of the tab panels and can be activated to display that panel.
tabpanel
The element that contains the content associated with a tab.
When a tabbed interface is initialized, one tab panel is displayed and its associated tab is styled to indicate that it is active. When the user activates one of the other tab elements, the previously displayed tab panel is hidden, the tab panel associated with the activated tab becomes visible, and the tab is considered "active".

```js
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  VERSION,
  ViewChild,
  ViewChildren
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("tabs1") tabs1: ElementRef;
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  tablist;
  tabs;
  panels;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.generateArrays();
    this.tablist = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      '[role="tablist"]'
    )[0];

    this.activateTab(this.tabs[0], true);
    this.setIndex();
  }

  generateArrays() {
    this.tabs = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
    this.panels = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      '[role="tabpanel"]'
    );
  }

  // For easy reference
  keys = {
    end: 35,
    home: 36,
    left: 37,
    up: 38,
    right: 39,
    down: 40,
    delete: 46,
    enter: 13,
    space: 32,
    tab: 9,
    shift: 16
  };

  // Add or subtract depending on key pressed
  direction = {
    37: -1,
    38: -1,
    39: 1,
    40: 1
  };

  // Bind listeners

  setIndex() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; ++i) {
      this.minusIndex(i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; ++i) {
      this.addIndex(i);
    }
  }
  minusIndex(index: number) {
    this.tabs[index].index = -1;
  }

  addIndex(index: number) {
    this.tabs[index].index = index;
  }
  // Activates any given tab panel
  activateTab(tab, setFocus) {
    if (tab.className == "child") {
      this.tabs = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button.child");
      this.panels = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("div.child");
    }
    if (tab.className == "parent") {
      this.tabs = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button.parent");
      this.panels = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("div.parent");
    }
    this.setIndex();
    setFocus = setFocus || true;

    this.activatePanels(tab, setFocus);
  }
  activatePanels(tab, setFocus) {
    //For parent
    // Deactivate all other this.tabs
    this.deactivateTabs();

    // Remove tabindex attribute
    tab.removeAttribute("tabindex");

    // Set the tab as selected
    tab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");

    // Get the value of aria-controls (which is an ID)
    var parentControls = tab.getAttribute("aria-controls");

    // Remove hidden attribute from tab panel to make it visible
    document.getElementById(parentControls).removeAttribute("hidden");

    // Set focus when required
    if (setFocus) {
      tab.focus();
    }

    //For chilren default panel open
    if (document.getElementById(parentControls).childElementCount > 0) {
      var a = document
        .getElementById(parentControls)
        .firstElementChild.getAttribute("tabindex");
      document
        .getElementById(parentControls)
        .firstElementChild.removeAttribute("tabindex");

      // Set the tab as selected
      document
        .getElementById(parentControls)
        .firstElementChild.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");

      // Get the value of aria-controls (which is an ID)
      var childControls = document
        .getElementById(parentControls)
        .firstElementChild.getAttribute("aria-controls");

      // Remove hidden attribute from tab panel to make it visible
      document.getElementById(childControls).removeAttribute("hidden");
    }
  }
  // When a tab is clicked, activateTab is fired to activate it
  clickEventListener(event: MouseEvent) {
    var tab = event.target;
    this.activateTab(tab, true);
  }

  // Handle keydown on this.tabs
  keydownEventListener(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    var key = event.keyCode;

    switch (key) {
      case this.keys.end:
        event.preventDefault();
        // Activate last tab
        this.focusLastTab();
        break;
      case this.keys.home:
        event.preventDefault();
        // Activate first tab
        this.focusFirstTab();
        break;

      // Up and down are in keydown
      // because we need to prevent page scroll >:)
      case this.keys.up:
      case this.keys.down:
        this.determineOrientation(event);
        break;

      case this.keys.tab:
        this.determineOrientation(event);
        break;
    }
  }

  // Handle keyup on this.tabs
  keyupEventListener(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    var key = event.keyCode;

    switch (key) {
      case this.keys.left:
      case this.keys.right:
        this.determineOrientation(event);
        break;
      case this.keys.delete:
        this.determineDeletable(event);
        break;
      case this.keys.enter:
      case this.keys.space:
        var tab = event.target;
        this.activateTab(tab, false);
        break;
    }
  }

  // When a tablistâ€™s aria-orientation is set to vertical,
  // only up and down arrow should function.
  // In all other cases only left and right arrow function.
  determineOrientation(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    // var vertical = this.tablist.getAttribute("aria-orientation") == "vertical";
    var proceed = false;

    if (key === this.keys.left || key === this.keys.right) {
      proceed = true;
    }
    if (key === this.keys.tab) {
      this.switchTabOnChildTabs(event);
    }
    if (proceed) {
      this.switchTabOnArrowPress(event);
    }
  }
  switchTabOnChildTabs(event) {
    this.tabs = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button.child");
    this.panels = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("div.child");
  }

  // Either focus the next, previous, first, or last tab
  // depending on key pressed
  switchTabOnArrowPress(event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.className == "child") {
      this.tabs = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button.child");
      this.panels = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("div.child");
    }
    if (event.currentTarget.className == "parent") {
      this.tabs = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button.parent");
      this.panels = this.tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("div.parent");
    }
    this.setIndex();

    var pressed = event.keyCode;

    if (this.direction[pressed]) {
      var target = event.target;
      if (target.index !== undefined) {
        if (this.tabs[target.index + this.direction[pressed]]) {
          this.tabs[target.index + this.direction[pressed]].focus();
        } else if (pressed === this.keys.left || pressed === this.keys.up) {
          this.focusLastTab();
        } else if (pressed === this.keys.right || pressed == this.keys.down) {
          this.focusFirstTab();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Deactivate all this.tabs and tab panels
  deactivateTabs() {
    for (var t = 0; t < this.tabs.length; t++) {
      this.tabs[t].setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
      this.tabs[t].setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
    }

    for (var p = 0; p < this.panels.length; p++) {
      this.panels[p].setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
    }
  }

  // Make a guess
  focusFirstTab() {
    this.tabs[0].focus();
  }

  // Make a guess
  focusLastTab() {
    this.tabs[this.tabs.length - 1].focus();
  }

  // Detect if a tab is deletable
  determineDeletable(event) {
    var target = event.target;

    if (target.getAttribute("data-deletable") !== null) {
      // Delete target tab
      this.deleteTab(event);

      // Update arrays related to this.tabs widget
      this.generateArrays();

      // Activate the closest tab to the one that was just deleted
      if (target.index - 1 < 0) {
        this.activateTab(this.tabs[0], false);
      } else {
        this.activateTab(this.tabs[target.index - 1], false);
      }
    }
  }

  // Deletes a tab and its panel
  deleteTab(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var panel = document.getElementById(target.getAttribute("aria-controls"));

    target.parentElement.removeChild(target);
    panel.parentElement.removeChild(panel);
  }

  // Determine whether there should be a delay
  // when user navigates with the arrow keys
  determineDelay() {
    var hasDelay = this.tablist.hasAttribute("data-delay");
    var delay: any;

    if (hasDelay) {
      var delayValue = this.tablist.getAttribute("data-delay");
      if (delayValue) {
        delay = delayValue;
      } else {
        // If no value is specified, default to 300ms
        delay = 300;
      }
    }

    return delay;
  }
}
```

```css
.tabs {
  width: 20em;
  font-family: "lucida grande", sans-serif;
}

[role="tablist"] {
  margin: 0 0 -0.1em;
  overflow: visible;
}

[role="tab"] {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  background: hsl(220, 20%, 94%);
}

[role="tab"]:hover::before,
[role="tab"]:focus::before,
[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
  border-top: 3px solid hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  content: '';
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"] {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
  outline: 0;
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]:not(:focus):not(:hover)::before {
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(218, 96%, 48%);
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0.3em;
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
  box-shadow: none;
  content: '';
}

[role="tab"]:hover,
[role="tab"]:focus,
[role="tab"]:active {
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

[role="tab"]:hover::before,
[role="tab"]:focus::before {
  border-color: hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
}

[role="tabpanel"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.7em;
  border: 1px solid hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  border-radius: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
}

[role="tabpanel"]:focus {
  border-color: hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  outline: 0;
}

[role="tabpanel"]:focus::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  border-radius: 0 0 0.2em 0.2em;
  content: '';
}

[role="tabpanel"] p {
  margin: 0;
}

[role="tabpanel"] * + p {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs" #tabs1>
    <div role="tablist" aria-label="Entertainment">
        <button
      role="tab"
      (click)="clickEventListener($event)"
      (keydown)="keydownEventListener($event)"
      (keyup)="keyupEventListener($event)"
      aria-selected="true"
      aria-controls="nils-tab"
      id="nils"
      class="parent"
    >
      parent1
    </button>

        <button role="tab"
              (click)="clickEventListener($event)"
      (keydown)="keydownEventListener($event)"
      (keyup)="keyupEventListener($event)"
            aria-selected="false"
            aria-controls="agnes-tab"
            id="agnes"
            tabindex="-1"    class="parent">
parent2
    </button>
    </div>
    <!-- class="parent" 1 div  -->
    <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="nils-tab" aria-labelledby="nils" class="parent">
        <button
      role="tab"
      (click)="clickEventListener($event)"
      (keydown)="keydownEventListener($event)"
      (keyup)="keyupEventListener($event)"
      aria-selected="true"
      aria-controls="aa-tab"
      id="aa"
      class="child"
      tabindex="0"

    >
      AA
    </button>
        <button
      role="tab"
      (click)="clickEventListener($event)"
      (keydown)="keydownEventListener($event)"
      (keyup)="keyupEventListener($event)"
      aria-selected="false"
      aria-controls="ab-tab"
      id="ab"
      tabindex="0"
      class="child"
    >
      AB
    </button>
        <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="aa-tab" aria-labelledby="aa" class="child" hidden="">
            hii AA
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="ab-tab" aria-labelledby="ab" class="child" hidden="">
            hii AB
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- class="parent" 2 div  -->
    <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="agnes-tab" aria-labelledby="agnes" hidden="" class="parent">
        <button
      role="tab"
      (click)="clickEventListener($event)"
      (keydown)="keydownEventListener($event)"
      (keyup)="keyupEventListener($event)"
      aria-selected="true"
      aria-controls="ba-tab"
      id="ba"
      class="child"
      tabindex="0"

    >
      BA
    </button>
        <button
      role="tab"
      (click)="clickEventListener($event)"
      (keydown)="keydownEventListener($event)"
      (keyup)="keyupEventListener($event)"
      aria-selected="false"
      aria-controls="bb-tab"
      id="bb"
      tabindex="0"
      class="child"
    >
      BB
    </button>
        <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="ba-tab" aria-labelledby="ba" class="child" hidden="">
            hii BA
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="bb-tab" aria-labelledby="bb" class="child" hidden="">
            hii BB
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```